# How to overwrite password_reset HTML templates

Tags: html, django, templates

What I'm trying to do is overwrite the default HTML templates that django uses for password_reset, password_reset_done, password_reset_confirm,and password_reset_complete. When I added a custom template to the first URL (password_reset) it actually worked perfectly. I could type the email that's associated with the user and proceed with the reset process, but when I tried to add a custom template for the password_reset_done view, the password_reset view no longer works and I get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'password_reset_done' not found. 'password_reset_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Here's my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
# imports for views at a gloabl level (aka other django apps)
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    login,
    logout,
    password_reset,
    password_reset_done,
    password_reset_confirm,
    password_reset_complete
)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html'}),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name': 'accounts/logout.html'}),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
    url(r'^profile/edit$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    url(r'^change-password$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
    url(r'^reset-password$', password_reset, {'template_name': 'accounts/reset_password.html'}),
    url(r'^reset-password/done/$', password_reset_done, {'template_name': 'accounts/password_reset_done.html'}),
    url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
    password_reset_confirm, {'template_name': 'accounts/password_reset_confirm.html'}),
    url(r'^reset-password/complete/$', password_reset_complete, {'template_name': 'accounts/password_reset_complete.html'})
]
```

NOTE: If I replace password_reset_done and all the others after with their proper name='password_reset_done, name='password_reset_confirm', name='password_reset_complete' parameters everything functions properly, but then I'm stuck with the default templates.

here's the urls.py when it functions:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html'}),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name': 'accounts/logout.html'}),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
    url(r'^profile/edit$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    url(r'^change-password$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
    url(r'^reset-password$', password_reset, {'template_name': 'accounts/reset_password.html'}),
    url(r'^reset-password/done/$', password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
    password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset-password/complete/$', password_reset_complete, name='password_reset_complete')
]
```

Only the first template can be changed without causing any errors. I'm still relatively new to django and I didn't find anything in the documentation that helped me solve this problem.

I'll leave other potentially important code below

from settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add names for those URLs, like you have for your own ones. For example:

```
url(r'^reset-password/done/$', password_reset_done, {'template_name': 'accounts/password_reset_done.html'}, name='password_reset_done'),
```

Comment: Tried this solution and it worked. Thank you so much for your time. I'll be sure to select your answer as best and upvote.

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked for me.
`re_path(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(),
           {'template_name': "reset_password.html"},
           name='reset_password'),`

Comment: This didn't work for me. The view worked as expected, however it used the password reset template already in place. That said, we already overrode the templates, so maybe I have something subtly different about my system.

Answer (score 0):

The approved answer didn't work for me. This did:

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetConfirmView
# ...
class ActivateAccountConfirmView(PasswordResetConfirmView):
    template_name = "./registration/account_activate_confirm.html"
```

urls.py:

```
 re_path(
        r'^accounts/activate/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        ActivateAccountConfirmView.as_view(),
        name='account_activate_confirm'),
```

Context: I have a password reset as well as an account activation facility in my application. Also note that this isn't the view the original user asked about, but the same method should work.